# Transact-SQL Missing columns in PIVOT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table has a lot of columns but only the first two are needed

```
Mtype   join_date   Other
A   28/05/2014 00:00    xx
B   04/11/2014 00:00    xx
C   23/03/2007 00:00    xx
D   04/09/2013 00:00    xx
E   26/11/2014 00:00    xx
F   24/07/2011 00:00    xxx
G   28/05/2014 00:00    xx
A   20/06/2013 00:00    x
B   04/11/2014 00:00    x
C   20/06/2013 00:00    x
```

This is the result I would like to get

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Mtype | 2015-03 | 2015-02 | 2015-01 | 2014-12 | 2014-11 | 2014-10 | 2014-9 | 2014-8 | 2014-7 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| A     |      45 |       7 |      54 |     875 |      45 |       7 |     54 |    875 |     25 |
| B     |       7 |      78 |      78 |       7 |       7 |      78 |     78 |      7 |     78 |
| C     |     546 |       6 |      87 |       5 |      45 |       6 |     87 |      5 |     25 |
| D     |      54 |      78 |      54 |       8 |      54 |      78 |     54 |      7 |      7 |
| E     |      78 |      78 |       7 |      45 |      78 |      78 |      7 |     45 |      6 |
| F     |      46 |      54 |       6 |       8 |      46 |      54 |      6 |      8 |     75 |
| G     |      54 |      87 |      87 |       7 |      54 |      87 |     87 |     45 |      8 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Code

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) + ']', 
          '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) as join_date FROM MD T0) PV  
           ORDER BY join_date DESC

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT Mtype, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) as join_date FROM MD T0
) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(join_date) 
  FOR join_date IN( ' + @cols + ')' +
') AS p ;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

The issue I have is that I only see three columns Mtype, (date),(date) depending on

```
ORDER BY join_date DESC
    +-------+---------+---------+
    | Mtype | 2015-09 | 2015-08 | 
    +-------+---------+---------+-
    | A     |      45 |       7 | 
    | B     |       7 |      78 | 
    | C     |     546 |       6 | 
    | D     |      54 |      78 | 
    | E     |      78 |      78 | 
    | F     |      46 |      54 | 
    | G     |      54 |      87 | 
    +-------+---------+---------+
```

those two columns are either DESC 2015-09 and 2015-08 or ASC 1989-07 and 1990-05. 
My question is what is wrong with my query that I only see 2 date columns instead of all of them (over 100).

Comment: `SELECT @query` instead of executing it. What do you get?

Comment: One column of::::: : mtype
SELECT *
 FROM
 (
 SELECT mtype, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) as join_date FROM MD T0
 ) AS t
 PIVOT 
 (
 COUNT(join_date) 
 FOR join_date IN( [2015-09],[2015-08],[2015-07],[2015-06],[2015-05],[2015-04],[2015-03],[2015-02],[2015-01],[2014-12],[2014-11],[2014-10],[2014-09],[2014-08],[2014-07],[2014-06],[2014-05],[2014-04],[2014-03],[2014-02],[2014-01],[2013-12],[2013-11],[2013-10],[2013-09],[2013-08],[2013-07],[2013-06],[2013-05],[2013-04],[2013-03],[2013-02],[2013-01],[2012-12],[2012-11],[2012-10],[2012-09],[2012-08],[2012-07],[2012-06])) AS p ;

Comment: had to shrink it down to big to copy-paste in a comment

Comment: I think your problem is that you're counting the same column you're pivoting on (`join_date`). Try counting something else (add something to your internal `SELECT` for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you run this?

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR (MAX)

CREATE TABLE #VALS (VALS NVARCHAR(4000))

INSERT INTO #VALS
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) 
FROM MD T0
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120)

SELECT @COLS = COALESCE(@COLS+', ','') + '[' + VALS + ']' FROM #VALS

SET @QUERY = '
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT MTYPE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), join_date, 120) AS join_date, COUNT(*) AS RECORDS
FROM MD T0)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
PIVOT(SUM(RECORDS) FOR join_date IN ('+@cols+')) PIV'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Invalid column name '2015-09'.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why yours doesn't work, but this is generally the method I use for a dynamic pivot (see edited post).